# "how can i reindex my coordinate database?"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, coordinates

I have some coordinates like this (id, X, Y):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTdZF.png)

want to re-index id's like this :
now using loop but it is very slowly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6TVx.png)

Comment: Please add your code that written a loop

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the speed depends on the implementation that you incorporate in the body of the for loop.

I propose two possible solutions.

The first is by using higher orders.

```
old_id = df.sort_values(by=['id'])["id"].tolist()
old_id_unique = df.sort_values(by=['id'])["id"].unique().tolist()
new_id = list(range(0, len(old_id)))
def get_new_id(x):
    index = old_id_unique.index(x)
    return new_id[index]
    
df['id'] =  list(map(get_new_id, old_id))

print(df)
```

And finally using a classic loop but slightly changing the implementation with respect to a "normative" solution.

```
old_id = df.sort_values(by=['id'])["id"].tolist()
old_id_unique = df.sort_values(by=['id'])["id"].unique()
new_id = list(range(0, len(old_id)))

for i in enumerate(old_id_unique):
    index_position = i[0]
    df['id'].replace({i[1]: str(new_id[index_position])}, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

For optimization reasons, higher order functions are usually faster.